# CodenameOne google maps - some markers not appearing

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

Using the fantastic Native Google Maps cn1lib, I'm attempting to place markers on the map, first one representing the user, then another slew of them representing objects from my database.  The first marker always plunks down fine, and I can relocate it (by erasing it and creating a new one in the new position), but the subsequent markers don't show on the map.  I get no errors in the simulator or on an Android device, but on both the additional markers don't show.  The code looks like this:

```
class MyClass{
    LinkedList<MapContainer.MapObject> towerMarkers;
    MapContainer towerMap;

    public void displayTowers(ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> towers){
        if(towerMarkers == null){
            towerMarkers = new LinkedList<>();
        }else{
            for(MapContainer.MapObject marker: towerMarkers){
                towerMap.removeMapObject(marker);
            }
            towerMarkers.clear();
        }

        for(HashMap<String, Object> obj: towers){
            towerMarkers.add(towerMap.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(FontImage.createMaterial(
                    FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS_INPUT_ANTENNA, cellTowerMarker, 3), false), 
                    new Coord(Double.parseDouble((String)obj.get("latitude")), Double.parseDouble((String)obj.get("longitude"))), 
                    "", "", null));
        }
    }
...
```

The code that works is very similar:

```
    towerMap.addTapListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    int x = evt.getX();
                    int y = evt.getY();
                    Coord tapCoord = towerMap.getCoordAtPosition(x, y);
                    if(myLocationMarker != null){
                            towerMap.removeMapObject(myLocationMarker);
                    }
                    myLocationMarker = towerMap.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LOCATION_ON, userLocationMarker, 4),
                            false), tapCoord, null, null, null);
                    findLongitudeField(f).setText(Double.toString(tapCoord.getLongitude()));
                    findLatitudeField(f).setText(Double.toString(tapCoord.getLatitude()));
                    findBtnUseChosenLocation(f).setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
```

The only odd thing that I noticed is when I inspect the map markers, they all (including the one that appears) seem to have coordinates in total different system.  Instead of (35.789..., 32.1233...), they're more like (3897665.88999, 4277888.988884), but since the one that shows up is also like that, it doesn't seem to be a problem.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like it should work, I would suggest checking out that the coordinate values make sense in the debugger

Comment: When I call `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` on the `Point` of the markers, I get numbers much larger or smaller than I get for the location marker, but I don't really understand what they represent, since they're all much too large to be regular coordinates anyway.  What system are they in? For instance, latitude 4194764.488092139.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out, the longitude and latitude values had accidentally gotten switched...